# Using $window.history.pushState results in a redirection

Tags: angularjs

HTML:

```
<div class="mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-card__video masonry-brick" ng-repeat="video in vm.videos" ng-click="vm.popupVideo(video)">
  <div class="mdl-card__media">
    <img ng-src="{{ video.poster }}" width="100%" height="100%" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
    {{ video.description }}
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
    <i class="material-icons md-72 md-white">play_circle_filled</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
vm.popupVideo = function (video) {
      var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: '/videoModal/videoModal.view.html',
        controller: 'videoModal',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        size: 'md',
        resolve: {
          videoData: function () {
            return video;
          }
        }
      });

    };
```

Popup Controller:

```
function videoModal ($uibModalInstance, videoData, $sce, $location, $window, $timeout) {
    var vm = this;

    $window.history.pushState("abc", "Title", "/watch/skfhskf");
}
```

Basically, when I clicked an element, it will generates a popup. And I want to change the address bar url without redirection, isn't that what $window.history.pushState() supposed to do? But when I use it in the popup controller, the page redirects to /watch/skfhskf. What's the problem?

---

I think routing is where causing the problem. Here is my routing code:

```
function routeConfig ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'home/home.view.html',
        controller: 'homeCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
      })
      .when('/watch/:watchid', {
        templateUrl: 'watch/watch.view.html',
        controller: 'watchCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
      })
      .otherwise({
        template: '<h1>Unmatched url</h1>'
      });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }
```

Comment: Did you use routing in your angular application.? Routing maybe taking the control when the URL changes.

Comment: Yes, I did. How can I override it?

Comment: I agree with @sreeramu, I think routing is causing the change.Could you add your routing code?Also, what is the purpose for changing the URL?Are you just using it to keep track, or what?

Comment: @Satej S I need to change the url so that users can bookmark and stuff like that and the url will go into history.

Comment: The problem is that, if the user bookmarks it, you're going to need the route for /:watchid, so that can't be removed either.